# Execute bat file from same folder

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a Bat file with

```batch
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jre\bin/java" -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins/war/web-inf/jenkins-cli.jar" -s "http://localhost:8080" create-job "buildjob" < "config.xml"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jre\bin/java" -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins/war/web-inf/jenkins-cli.jar" -s "http://localhost:8080" safe-restart
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jre\bin/java" -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins/war/web-inf/jenkins-cli.jar" -s "http://localhost:8080" build buildjob -p "Path=/" -w -s
```

I couldn't get this running directly in PowerShell, so I put it into a bat file in the same folder as the script and added

```psh
cmd.exe /c 'ConfigureJenkinsJob.bat'
```

But that gives an error that the system couldn't find the specified file.

Answer (score 1):

The command is trying to run the batch file from the current working directory, which isn't necessarily the same folder in which the scripts reside. If you need to run another script from the same folder, use the `$MyInvocation` automatic variable to determine the parent folder:

```
$dir = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
cmd.exe /c "$dir\ConfigureJenkinsJob.bat"
```

Instead of using `cmd /c` you could also simply use the call operator (`&`), since batch files can be run directly from PowerShell:

```
$dir = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
& "$dir\ConfigureJenkinsJob.bat"
```